# Validate an input as JSON notation on iOS

Tags: ios, json, validation

I have an input field on an iOS app that accepts an NSString value.  I want to be able to validate the input as a JSON object.  For example:

```
NSString = @"{'foo':'bar'}" //would be validated as JSON notation
NSString = @"Hello world!" //would NOT be validated as JSON
```

I have tried using the following method:

```
[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:(id)obj]
```

However, it always returns false, even if the string input is something like {'hello':'world'}.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`isValidJSONObject` is not the way to see if a string represents valid JSON. It's meant to see if an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` can be converted to a JSON string.

To see if your JSON string is valid JSON, use the normal JSON serialization (`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`) and see if you get a valid result.

```
NSString *jsonString = ... // the JSON you wish to validate
NSError *error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding] options:0 error:&error];
if (result) {
    // string was valid JSON
} else {
    // string was not valid JSON
    // log error to see what was wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isValidJSONObject tests if an NSDictionary or NSArray can be converted into  a JSON object. It doesn't test if a JSON string is correct.

The way to check is

```
if ([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding] options:0 error:nil]) {
    //valid
}
```